# Git Freeze Important Version

Tags: git

i've many commits in my git repository for a project i am making, but it has come to be an official first version now. Therefore, i wanted to ask :

Is there a way to "stick" a version number to a particular revision in Git ? That is, instead of just keeping a log comment, be able to handle important versions differently,  like finding an important beta, finding v1.0 and so on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's tagging for you, check out http://learn.github.com/p/tagging.html

Comment: this link is out of date. see: https://lab.github.com/githubtraining/create-a-release-based-workflow

Answer (score 1):

Use signed tags. The important part about signed tags and/or tags with messages is that they are objects that get sent with the references.  With signed tags you can give your clients the peace of mind, as they would know that the tag was created by you.